# Insert in table only if two columns relationship is not duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I have a language table that contains a 'node_id' and a 'language' column.

```
|| *nid* || *language* ||
|| 8 || Chinese ||
|| 8 || Portuguese ||
|| 8 || German |
```

I'd like to insert new languages into it, but only if there isn't already a similar language entry for that particular nid. So according to exemple above, adding nid>8 and language> Chinese would have no effect.

How should i do to achieve that? Is there a type of query that would act as such, or should i first do check with PHP/MYSQL before inserting the row ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a UNIQUE constraint on the pair of columns in the MySQL database. Any query trying to add a duplicate row will fail.

Comment: Thanks steven for your answer, though how would i do that ? Should i create a primary key that is the 2values coupled together ?

Comment: Primary key would do the job (I think this would be what you want in this case), since they are unique by definition. It is also possible to declare columns that aren't part of the primary key to be unique.

Comment: Great i ll give this a try, one last thing though, how should i go for populating that primary key automatically with the value of the 2 columns ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by automatically here? You can just add rows in the same way as if you have a single-row primary key, there is no special treatment required at all.

Comment: Thank you all for your insights

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a unique key index with 2 of those columns:

CREATE  TABLE `lang` (
  `nid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `language` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `index_lang` (`nid` ASC, `language` ASC) );

Comment: Thanks Josues, but i don't get that part `index_lang (nid ASC, language ASC)` does that mean that index_lang automatically gets it s value from nid and language added together ?

Comment: That's right. That index is aware of both values and because is a UNIQUE type, checks that doesnt repeat in another row.