# Unique constraint, how to avoid duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

According to my previous Query [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404955/insert-in-table-only-if-two-columns-relationship-is-not-duplicated) i have a table that looks like this:

```
|| *nid* || *language* ||
|| 8 || Chinese ||
|| 8 || Portuguese ||
|| 8 || German |
```

In which 'nid' and 'language' have a unique constraint.

With this setup how can i make sure that the there wont be any duplicate when i try to insert a new row ?

**EDITED**

I am guessing I should try to make a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM lang WHERE nid = $nid AND language = $lang
```

If this return FALSE then i know i can now insert my data. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enforce the unique constraint by creating a unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table
ADD UNIQUE INDEX nid_language_unique (nid, language);
```

This constraint forbid two rows having the same nid and language.

Any query attempting to violate the constraint will fail.

As you want to ignore errors (and still abort the query), you can use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and [UPDATE IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO the_table (nid, language) VALUES (8, 'Chinese')
/* row not inserted and no error */
```

Comment: Thanks, it s actually what i did, though now if i add a duplicate i get an error, i am wondering how to avoid this ? I ll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: If you just want to ignore the error (and still not insert the row), use INSERT IGNORE. See [mysql insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have actually established a unique constraint in the database then MySQL will not let you insert the second row.  The statement will raise an exception.  You can trap and ignore that in your code.  If you're not interested in whether the row was added or not, you can use the IGNORE keyward in the MySQL INSERT INTO command and the row will either be added (if not there) or the command will complete without an error.

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT nid, language FROM lang WHERE nid = $nid AND language = $lang
>
> If this return FALSE then i know i can now insert my data. Is this correct ?

Yes, but you need to write:

```
$nid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nid']);
$lang = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lang']);
$query = SELECT nid, language FROM lang WHERE nid = '$nid' AND language = '$lang'
// notice the quotes                                ^    ^                ^     ^
```

If you forget these your query give an error (and be at risk from SQL-injection).

If you have a unique constraint, you can just go ahead and insert the data, because MySQL will do the above test for you.

Comment: THanks for the note Johan though i am using drupal DB API so it handle all of that stuff : )

Comment: @silk, If you don't use PDO you still need those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter in your code (not SQL, but the one you use to use SQL, like PHP, or else)

You can use MySQL max function and add one (like max(nid)+1  (but don't remember about MySQL's max function))

You can use a random number with 10 characters (so you'd would have a really really low risk to go into an error)

I used the first and last way many times.

And if you want to be sure that you won't have a duplicate, use the solutions from your last posts. Stuff like UNIQUE constraint will prevent you to insert twice the same nid or language (thus, if you don't handle it, your program will crash).