# Need help using UNIQUE keys on several columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

[image]

As you can see index_lang is a unique key that constrain the couple nid/ language.

Now if i insert values for nid and languages to something like this:

[image]

How then can i check with PHP if a row with a pair nid / language have already be inserted into that table as it seems that i can not retrieve the value of the index_lang key. I was assuming that this index_lang key would automatically get the value of the 2 column inserted, so according to the above table the row 1 unique key would get a value of : '1chinese'

**EDIT:** I am using drupal API to insert data in this table, the PHP code that insert the data right now looks like this:

```
foreach ( $user_lang as $k=>$v ){
    $lang_query = db_insert('my_table')
      ->fields(array(
        'nid' => $og_group->etid,
        'language' => $v))
      ->execute();  
}
```

$user_lang is an array of languages.

**Second Edit:**

I would us an IGNORE statement to insert my data to avoid duplicate and ignore errors though there is no such thing using the Drupal DB API, well if there is i have no ideas on how to do..

Comment: It looks like the answer to this is already provided in your other thread regarding this issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405619/unique-constraint-how-to-avoid-duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is not the same as a column. It is used for internal use by mysql and you can't read it as a column.

The above however should prevent you from inserting double entries. Just check it by trying to add a row with nid=1 and language="Chinese". You should get an error message (unique key violation.)

From php you could try to insert the row. If you just need it to not insert, you can use the error message to display something to the user.

If you want the current value updated you could use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in your sql.

And finally you could of course first do a `select ... from languages where nid=1 and language="Chinese"` and then decide what you want to do with it.

Comment: thanks for that explaination, So the only purpose of unique key is to through me an error in case of duplicate ?

Comment: Well, almost. The actual purpose is guaranteeing that the data is really unique, and you can trust the db on this without having to check it yourself. And that prevents errors, bugs and incorrect behaviors in many cases. You could enforce this by hand (or by home-written code) but it is error prone and you will forget it somewhere sometime. Using 'UNIQUE' your db will catch that. Showing an error is just to inform why the insert was rejected. (If you want to know more, read about data integrity and normalization.)

Answer (score 1):

First think of the SQL. You would need this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE nid=1 AND language='Chinese'
```

From this you can easily get the PHP - whose query will depend of if you are using `mysql` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve the value of `index_lang` it's an *index*.

```
SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE nid=1 AND language='Chinese'
```

Comment: Thanks yi_H for your answer but what does 1 stand for ?

Comment: for the number 1. you can retrieve `*` but you already have all the information, you just need to know whether the record exists...

Comment: @ed: obviously not. why you're asking it here?

Comment: @yi_H ok i got it but then i do not need a unique Key at all, i can just make sure that if a similar entry already exits not to re enter it using your query as a condition?

Comment: 1) if you have multiple clients and high contention then selecting won't help 2) you can put constraints in the database to make sure that your application logic is correct. if you *have* a performance issue *and* you trust your app then you can remove it. otherwise it's better to have it. 3) *read* the answers for your previous question.